# Pass objects from server interceptors to functions

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I created a simple Server Interceptor that retrieves the user based on the JWT token.

But now I would like to make it available to all the methods of my services.

At the moment im using decorators. But I would like to avoid having to decorate all the methods. In case, decorate only those that do not need the user.

Some one can give me a clue ?

here is my code:

```
class AuthInterceptor(grpc.ServerInterceptor):
"""Authorization Interceptor"""

def __init__(self, loader):
    self._loader = loader

def intercept_service(self, continuation, handler_call_details):
    # Authenticate if we not requesting token.
    if not handler_call_details.method.endswith('GetToken'):
        # My Authentication class.
        auth = EosJWTAuth()
        # Authenticate using the headers tokens to get the user.
        user = auth.authenticate(
            dict(handler_call_details.invocation_metadata))[0]

        # Do something here to pass the authenticated user to the functions.

    cont = continuation(handler_call_details)
    return cont
```

And I'd like my methods can to access the user in a way like this.

```
class UserService(BaseService, users_pb2_grpc.UserServicer):
"""User service."""

def get_age(self, request, context):
    """Get user's age"""
    user = context.get_user()
    # or user = context.user 
    # or user = self.user 
    # os user = request.get_user() 
    return pb.UserInfo(name=user.name, age=user.age)
```

Comment: @Lidi
I like this solution.
I had not thought about the metaclasses.

But in fact you're right. in the course of work I realized I needed more granularity for authentication.
Decorating each function by hand is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common need for web servers, and it is a good idea to add decorators to the handlers to explicitly set requirement for authentication/authorization. It helps readability, and reduces the overall complexity.

However, here is a workaround to solve your question. It uses Python metaclass to automatically decorate every servicer method.

```
import grpc
import functools
import six

def auth_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(request, context):
        if not func.__name__.endswith('GetToken'):
            auth = FooAuthClass()
            try:
                user = auth.authenticate(
                    dict(context.invocation_metadata)
                )[0]
                request.user = user
            except UserNotFound:
                context.abort(
                    grpc.StatusCode.UNAUTHENTICATED,
                    'Permission denied.',
                )
        return func(request, context)

    return wrapper

class AuthMeta:

    def __new__(self, class_name, bases, namespace):
        for key, value in list(namespace.items()):
            if callable(value):
                namespace[key] = auth_decorator(value)
        return type.__new__(self, class_name, bases, namespace)

class BusinessServer(FooServicer, six.with_metaclass(AuthMeta)):

    def LogicA(self, request, context):
        # request.user accessible
        ...

    def LogicGetToken(self, request, context):
        # request.user not accessible
        ...
```